# OpenGl Es Texture color incorrect

Tags: android, opengl-es, colors, error-handling, syntax-error

I'm following the book "Beginning Android C++ Game Development". Currently in chapter 5, the book's code can be downloaded from their website.

I have my followed the book upto chapter 4 without problems, but come chapter 5 when rendering textures, I get this:

http://i193.photobucket.com/albums/z127/johto760/error-1.png

as you can see the color is incorrect, I kind of expect something like this:

http://i193.photobucket.com/albums/z127/johto760/somewhatexpected.png

even in the second one the RGB is inverted, I'm using TGA files for images. I've been googling for solution since sunday and it's tuesday today.

Here's the relevant code that I'm working on:

```
     SampleTask.cpp
        namespace {
            float verts[] = {-0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
                -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f};

            unsigned short indices[] = {0, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1};

        }

        SampleTask::SampleTask(Framework::Renderer* renderer,
                const unsigned int priority) :
                Framework::Task(priority), m_state(RUNNING), m_renderer(renderer), m_readBytes(
                        0), m_TGABuffer(NULL), m_file("test.tga"), m_fileLength(0) {

            m_renderable.SetGeometry(&m_geometry);
            m_renderable.SetShader(&m_textureShader);
        }

        SampleTask::~SampleTask() {
            m_renderer->RemoveRenderable(&m_renderable);
            m_renderer->RemoveTexture(&m_texture);
            m_renderer->RemoveShader(&m_textureShader);

            if (m_TGABuffer) {
                delete[] static_cast<char*>(m_TGABuffer);
                m_TGABuffer = 0;
            }
        }

        bool SampleTask::Start() {
            Framework::Geometry* pGeometry = m_renderable.GetGeometry();
            pGeometry->SetName("quad");
            pGeometry->SetVertexBuffer(verts);
            pGeometry->SetNumVertices(4);
            pGeometry->SetIndexBuffer(indices);
            pGeometry->SetNumIndices(6);

            pGeometry->SetNumVertexPositionElements(3);
            pGeometry->SetNumTexCoordsElements(2);
            pGeometry->SetVertexStride(sizeof(float) * 5);

            bool success = false;
            if (m_file.Open()) {
                m_fileLength = m_file.Length();

                m_TGABuffer = new char[m_fileLength];

                m_state = LOADING_FILE;
                success = true;
            }

            return success;
        }

        void SampleTask::Stop() {
            m_renderer->RemoveRenderable(&m_renderable);
        }

        void SampleTask::Update() {
            switch (m_state) {

            case (LOADING_FILE): {
                void* currentDataPos = static_cast<char*>(m_TGABuffer)
                        + (sizeof(char) * m_readBytes);

                size_t bytesRead = 0;
                m_file.Read(currentDataPos, 512 * 1024, bytesRead);
                m_readBytes += bytesRead;
                if (m_readBytes == m_fileLength) {

                    m_state = CREATE_TEXTURE;
                }
            }
                break;

            case (CREATE_TEXTURE): {
                Framework::TGAFile tgaFile(m_TGABuffer);

                Framework::Texture::Header textureHeader;
                textureHeader.m_width = tgaFile.GetWidth();
                textureHeader.m_height = tgaFile.GetHeight();

                textureHeader.m_bytesPerPixel = 4;

                textureHeader.m_dataSize = textureHeader.m_width
                        * textureHeader.m_height * textureHeader.m_bytesPerPixel;

                m_texture.SetData(textureHeader, tgaFile.GetImageData());

                m_textureShader.SetTexture(&m_texture);

                m_renderer->AddTexture(&m_texture);

                m_renderer->AddShader(&m_textureShader);

                m_renderer->AddRenderable(&m_renderable);

                m_state = RUNNING;

            }
                break;
            };
        }
```

---

```
   Renderer.cpp
    void Renderer::Update() {
        if (m_initialized) {

            glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
            glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

            for (RenderableVectorIterator iter = m_renderables.begin();
                    iter != m_renderables.end(); iter++) {
                Renderable* pRenderable = *iter;
                if (pRenderable) {
                    Draw(pRenderable);
                }
            }
            eglSwapBuffers(m_display, m_surface);
        }
    }

    void Renderer::Init() {

        // initialize OpenGL ES and EGL

        /*
         * Here specify the attributes of the desired configuration.
         * Below, we select an EGLConfig with at least 8 bits per color
         * component compatible with on-screen windows
         */
        const EGLint attribs[] = {
        EGL_RENDERABLE_TYPE, EGL_OPENGL_ES2_BIT,
        EGL_SURFACE_TYPE, EGL_WINDOW_BIT,
        EGL_BLUE_SIZE, 8,
        EGL_GREEN_SIZE, 8,
        EGL_RED_SIZE, 8,
        EGL_NONE };

        EGLint format;
        EGLint numConfigs;
        EGLConfig config;

        m_display = eglGetDisplay(EGL_DEFAULT_DISPLAY);

        eglInitialize(m_display, NULL, NULL);

        /* Here, the application chooses the configuration it desires. In this
         * sample, we have a very simplified selection process, where we pick
         * the first EGLConfig that matches our criteria */
        eglChooseConfig(m_display, attribs, &config, 1, &numConfigs);

        /* EGL_NATIVE_VISUAL_ID is an attribute of the EGLConfig that is
         * guaranteed to be accepted by ANativeWindow_setBuffersGeometry().
         * As soon as we picked a EGLConfig, we can safely reconfigure the
         * ANativeWindow buffers to match, using EGL_NATIVE_VISUAL_ID. */
        eglGetConfigAttrib(m_display, config, EGL_NATIVE_VISUAL_ID, &format);

        ANativeWindow_setBuffersGeometry(m_state->window, 0, 0, format);

        m_surface = eglCreateWindowSurface(m_display, config, m_state->window,
        NULL);

        EGLint contextAttribs[] = {
        EGL_CONTEXT_CLIENT_VERSION, 2,
        EGL_NONE };
        m_context = eglCreateContext(m_display, config, NULL, contextAttribs);

        eglMakeCurrent(m_display, m_surface, m_surface, m_context);

        eglQuerySurface(m_display, m_surface, EGL_WIDTH, &m_width);
        eglQuerySurface(m_display, m_surface, EGL_HEIGHT, &m_height);

        for (TextureVectorIterator iter = m_textures.begin();
                iter != m_textures.end(); ++iter) {
            Texture* pCurrent = *iter;
            pCurrent->Init();
        }

        for (ShaderVectorIterator iter = m_shaders.begin(); iter != m_shaders.end();
                ++iter) {
            Shader* pCurrent = *iter;
            pCurrent->Link();
        }

        m_initialized = true;

    }

    void Renderer::Draw(Renderable* renderable) {
        assert(renderable);
        if (renderable) {
            Geometry* geometry = renderable->GetGeometry();
            Shader* shader = renderable->GetShader();

            assert(geometry && shader);
            if (geometry && shader) {
                shader->Setup(*renderable);

                glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, geometry->GetNumIndices(),
                GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, geometry->GetIndexBuffer());
            }
        }
    }
```

---

```
Texture.cpp
    void Texture::Init() {
        GLint packBits = 4;
        GLint internalFormat = GL_RGBA;
        GLenum format = GL_RGBA;
        switch (m_header.m_bytesPerPixel) {
        case 1: {
            packBits = 1;
            internalFormat = GL_ALPHA;
            format = GL_ALPHA;
        }
            break;
        };

        glGenTextures(1, &m_id);

        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_id);

        glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, packBits);

        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, internalFormat, m_header.m_width,
                m_header.m_height, 0, format, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, m_imageData);
    }
```

---

```
TextureShader.cpp
    m_vertexShaderCode =
    "attribute vec4 a_vPosition;        \n"
    "attribute vec2 a_texCoord;         \n"
    "varying   vec2 v_texCoord;         \n"
    "void main(){                       \n"
    "    gl_Position = a_vPosition;     \n"
    "    v_texCoord = a_texCoord;       \n"
    "}                                  \n";

m_fragmentShaderCode =
    "precision highp float;                             \n"
    "varying vec2 v_texCoord;                               \n"
    "uniform sampler2D s_texture;                           \n"
    "void main(){                                           \n"
    "    gl_FragColor = texture2D(s_texture, v_texCoord);   \n"
    "}                                                      \n";
```

---

```
    void TextureShader::Link() {
        Shader::Link();

        m_positionAttribHandle = glGetAttribLocation(m_programId, "a_vPosition");
        m_texCoordAttribHandle = glGetAttribLocation(m_programId, "a_texCoord");
        m_samplerHandle = glGetUniformLocation(m_programId, "s_texture");

    }

    void TextureShader::Setup(Renderable& renderable){
        assert(m_texture);
        Geometry* pGeometry = renderable.GetGeometry();
        if (pGeometry && m_texture) {
            Shader::Setup(renderable);

            glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
            glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_texture->GetId());
            glUniform1i(m_samplerHandle, 0);

            glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
            glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

            glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
            glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

            glVertexAttribPointer(m_positionAttribHandle,
                    pGeometry->GetNumVertexPositionElements(),
                    GL_FLOAT,
                    GL_FALSE, pGeometry->GetVertexStride(),
                    pGeometry->GetVertexBuffer());
            glEnableVertexAttribArray (m_positionAttribHandle);

            glVertexAttribPointer(m_texCoordAttribHandle,
                    pGeometry->GetNumTexCoordsElements(),
                    GL_FLOAT,
                    GL_FALSE, pGeometry->GetVertexStride(),
                    &static_cast<GLfloat*>(pGeometry->GetVertexBuffer())[pGeometry->GetNumVertexPositionElements()]);
            glEnableVertexAttribArray (m_texCoordAttribHandle);

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Found what was wrong.

I decided to use the header and cpp files from the website of the book, then one by one I copy-pasted each cpp file from my own version of the code, it turns out to be a "calculation error" for the imagedata size of TGA files.

My error is in the code:

```
m_imageData = static_cast<void*>(static_cast<char*>(data) + sizeof(m_header));
```

I was calculating the sizeof "m_header" variable, when instead I should be calculating the sizeof TGAHeader class which is I believe is 18 bytes or something, so I changed m_header to TGAHeader like so:

```
m_imageData = static_cast<void*>(static_cast<char*>(data) + sizeof(TGAHeader));
```

Now the colors are correct, I also changed the format from GL_RGB to GL_BGR_EXT and kept the internal format to be GL_RGB, so as to invert the color when entering the buffers of gl.